# angularjs factory properties aren't accessible

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-service

I am trying to build an Angularjs factory,
I'm writing the script on seperate module and then inject:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ngAnimate', 'ngTouch', 'myModule']);
```

but when I try to log a factory's property in the run stage, it's undefined:

```
console.log(myFactory.update()); // undefined
```

Here is my factory implementation, did it according to the angularjs documentation:

```
    var myModule = angular.module('myModule', []);

    myModule.factory('myFactory', function() {
    return {
    controls: {
      'text_size'        : 1,           // text size level; default: 1; type: integer; options: [1-5]
      'underline'        : false,      // underline mode state; default: FALSE; type: boolean; options: [true (on), false (off)]
      'zoom'             : 1,         // zoom level; default: 1; type: integer; options: [1-5]
      'contrast'         : null,     // contrast mode; default: null; type: string, options: [null, 'dark', 'light']
      'background_color' : null,    //  background color; default: null; type: string; options: ['black', 'darkgrey', 'grey', 'red', 'orange', 'yellow', 'green', 'lightblue', 'blue', 'purple', 'pink', null]
      'headlines_color'  : null,   // headlines color; default: null; type: string; options: ['black', 'darkgrey', 'grey', 'red', 'orange', 'yellow', 'green', 'lightblue', 'blue', 'purple', 'pink', null]
      'text_color'       : null,  // text color; default: null; type: string; options: ['black', 'darkgrey', 'grey', 'red', 'orange', 'yellow', 'green', 'lightblue', 'blue', 'purple', 'pink', null]
      'focus_indicator'  : {     // focus indicator mode and color;
        'active'         : true,// default: true (on); type: boolean; options: [true (on), false (off)]
        'color'          : 'black', // default: black (change to match website style), type: string; options: ['black', 'darkgrey', 'grey', 'red', 'orange', 'yellow', 'green', 'lightblue', 'blue', 'purple', 'pink', null]
      },
      'media_controls'   : false,// default: false (change to match website style), type: boolean; options: [true (on), false (off)]
    },
    update: function(control, value) {
      this.controls[control] = value;
    }
  }
    });
```

also tried to do it this way:

```
var myModule = angular.module('myModule', []);

myModule.factory('myFactory', function() {
  var finalInstance = function() {
    this.controls = {
      'text_size'        : 1,           // text size level; default: 1; type: integer; options: [1-5]
      'underline'        : false,      // underline mode state; default: FALSE; type: boolean; options: [true (on), false (off)]
      'zoom'             : 1,         // zoom level; default: 1; type: integer; options: [1-5]
      'contrast'         : null,     // contrast mode; default: null; type: string, options: [null, 'dark', 'light']
      'background_color' : null,    //  background color; default: null; type: string; options: ['black', 'darkgrey', 'grey', 'red', 'orange', 'yellow', 'green', 'lightblue', 'blue', 'purple', 'pink', null]
      'headlines_color'  : null,   // headlines color; default: null; type: string; options: ['black', 'darkgrey', 'grey', 'red', 'orange', 'yellow', 'green', 'lightblue', 'blue', 'purple', 'pink', null]
      'text_color'       : null,  // text color; default: null; type: string; options: ['black', 'darkgrey', 'grey', 'red', 'orange', 'yellow', 'green', 'lightblue', 'blue', 'purple', 'pink', null]
      'focus_indicator'  : {     // focus indicator mode and color;
        'active'         : true,// default: true (on); type: boolean; options: [true (on), false (off)]
        'color'          : 'black', // default: black (change to match website style), type: string; options: ['black', 'darkgrey', 'grey', 'red', 'orange', 'yellow', 'green', 'lightblue', 'blue', 'purple', 'pink', null]
      },
      'media_controls'   : false,// default: false (change to match website style), type: boolean; options: [true (on), false (off)]
    };

    this.update = function(control, value) {
      this.controls[control] = value;
    };
  };

  return new finalInstance();
});
```

nothing works...

any suggestions?

Comment: `this` which you are using in `this.controls[control] = value;` is not same as that `this` of service, I'd say using `service` here would be better approach

Comment: Hey is it like you are getting undefined on calling update method of the factory object? Have you added return statement in the update method in your code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think using service would be appropriate here(could use factory as well), as you are messing up to having `this` reference inside updated method.

Also while logging method you are not returning anything from update method, so any case it is going to print `undefined` until you return anything. I think you should return controls to see updated controls list from update method.

**Code**

```
var myModule = angular.module('myModule', []);

myModule.service('myFactory', function() {
  var self = this; //this self will ensure you are accessing `this` correctly
  self.controls = {
    'text_size': 1, // text size level; default: 1; type: integer; options: [1-5]
    'underline': false, // underline mode state; default: FALSE; type: boolean; options: [true (on), false (off)]
    'zoom': 1, // zoom level; default: 1; type: integer; options: [1-5]
    'contrast': null, // contrast mode; default: null; type: string, options: [null, 'dark', 'light']
    'background_color': null, //  background color; default: null; type: string; options: ['black', 'darkgrey', 'grey', 'red', 'orange', 'yellow', 'green', 'lightblue', 'blue', 'purple', 'pink', null]
    'headlines_color': null, // headlines color; default: null; type: string; options: ['black', 'darkgrey', 'grey', 'red', 'orange', 'yellow', 'green', 'lightblue', 'blue', 'purple', 'pink', null]
    'text_color': null, // text color; default: null; type: string; options: ['black', 'darkgrey', 'grey', 'red', 'orange', 'yellow', 'green', 'lightblue', 'blue', 'purple', 'pink', null]
    'focus_indicator': { // focus indicator mode and color;
      'active': true, // default: true (on); type: boolean; options: [true (on), false (off)]
      'color': 'black', // default: black (change to match website style), type: string; options: ['black', 'darkgrey', 'grey', 'red', 'orange', 'yellow', 'green', 'lightblue', 'blue', 'purple', 'pink', null]
    },
    'media_controls': false, // default: false (change to match website style), type: boolean; options: [true (on), false (off)]
  };
  self.update = function(control, value) {
    self.controls[control] = value; //accessing correct controls object
    return self.controls; //returning controls
  };
});
```

Comment: great, worked! :)

by the way, I also tried to log controls property and it returned undefined.. so the solution was to make it a service.. thanks!!

Comment: @YonatanNaxon Glad to know that. Thanks :-)

Comment: @YonatanNaxon no.. I made to service because you are playing with `this` context..Though this can be possible with factory too..